# How to export selected column of datagidview to excel sheet in C# windows form

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I have many rows and 8 column in my `DataGridView`. I am using `MySQL` database, I want to export only 2 or three selected column data of `DataGridView` to an `Excel` sheet with their header on button click. I have already tried the code but that code copy all the column with out header.
Please give me the code so I will do my task.
Thanks

Here this is my code : but this code copy all the column with out header in excel.

```
    private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Int16 i, j;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        for (i = 0; i <= dgvSlipRecord.RowCount - 2; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= dgvSlipRecord.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dgvSlipRecord[j, i].Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"d:\csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code you've written so we can help you correct it.

Comment: please saw the code I had updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't make it clear how you want to decide to choose which columns to export so I've created a simple collection of column indices called `ColumnsToInclude`.  I then use this to reference into the dgv collections.  I've added a loop to add the column headers to the output. Hopefully this will be enough for you to complete your colution.

```
   private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
        Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        int[] ColumnsToInclude = { 0, 2 };
        Int16 i;

        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        for (int ix = 0; ix < ColumnsToInclude.Length; ix++)
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, ix + 1] = dgvSlipRecord.Columns[ColumnsToInclude[ix]].HeaderText;
        for (i = 0; i <= dgvSlipRecord.RowCount - 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ColumnsToInclude.Length; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgvSlipRecord[ColumnsToInclude[j], i].Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"c:\temp\csharp.net-informations.xls", XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
    }
```